# ipad page curl control for customisation

Tags: objective-c, google-maps, ipad, controls

I have noticed that on the iPad the google maps app has a very cool page curl control that sits in the bottom right hand corner that allows the user to change configuration settings.

Is this control accessible for everyday developers, or was in built specifically for google maps on the iPad?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The control itself is built-into UIKit, but it's private API. You could just use custom images with a button, however.

A similar page-curl *effect* can be achieved with

```
theConfigCtrler.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl;
[self presentModalViewController:theConfigCtrler animated:YES];
```

(This is just "similar" — the page is curled up to reveal over 90% of the background controller.)

Comment: thanks, and theConfigCtrler is a ViewController? BTW, how do you know that its in UIKit but its private?

Comment: @Mark: (1) Yes. (2) Disassembly.